# How to add to a pipeline in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

Let's say I have two files, `f1.txt` and `f2.txt`. `f1.txt` has some corrections that need to be made, after which both files will need to be processed together. How do I merge the output of `f1.txt` corrections to the pipeline with `f2.txt` data?

Here is an illustration:

```
Get-Content f1.txt |
% {
    $_ #SOME OPERATION
} # How do I merge this output into the next pipeline?
Get-Content f2.txt |
% {
    #COMBINED OPERATIONS on f1.txt output and f2.txt
} > output.txt
```

I understand I can save the first operation into a temporary file and read from it again for the combined operation:

```
...
} > temp.txt
Get-Content temp.txt, f2.txt |
...
```

But is there a way to do it without creating buffer files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap multiple commands in single `SciptBlock` and invoke it:

```
& {
    Get-Content f1.txt |
    % {
        $_ #SOME OPERATION
    }
    Get-Content f2.txt
} |
% {
    #COMBINED OPERATIONS on f1.txt output and f2.txt
} > output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.